# Should I subclass only for UIAppearance

Tags: ios, uiappearance

Basically, I'm refactoring an app after reading about UIAppearance. Most of my UI changes were in the storyboard or in viewDidLoad, and customizing each control was a pain in the ass.

I have a cell, that contains two labels, let's say `bigLabel`and `smallLabel`. I'd like `bigLabel` to be bold, and `smallLabel` not to be. From [this lecture](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/08/24/using-appearance-proxy-to-style-apps.html), I should subclass both labels and apply the appearance on the different classes.

My question is, which practice is the best :

- Subclass both labels
- Just modify the attributes through the storyboard
- Anything else ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When you make UI changes in the storyboard - you're skipping the code part. That's the whole idea of using the storyboard for standard stuff, like fonts, colours and font sizes. You can do it in code, if you want to - but you don't do it with code AND storyboard. Its one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the attributes through the storyboard. Why subclass if you can avoid it? Also, code will be cleaner.

Comment: The problem is, it kinda "break" the UIAppearance overriding. It means that if I want to change the font, I need to change it both in the code AND in the storyboard... Is that the right way to do it ?

Comment: How can you do it in code and the Storyboard? - The code would overwrite the Storyboard's implementation - not so? 
Like I said earlier - it's one or the other. Not both

Answer (score 0):

UILabel currently does not conform to UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR. Check the header. There are some work arounds to this, such as overriding these properties in a category and adding UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR. To determine whether to use UIAppearance or your storyboard you have to assess how difficult it would be to make changes in your context. For a very simple app, this is perhaps acceptable. However, imagine if you tried to implement something like a theme change! The storyboard settings approach breaks down rather rapidly as does setting stuff in code for every view even if you abstract this out into a header. Change will be painful, very painful.